# Django - Publish views publicly using unique url

Tags: django, django-views

I have an app where users login, manage some options and create model's instances to generate views according to their needs. This is done in private session only.

I want to add a publish function to my app where users could give public access to views they have managed.

My first idea was to output static html files of user's views using unique url for each published view. Those static files would be stored on the app server. I don't know if this idea is possible and if it is, I know it could be difficult to manage the bunch of updates, delete, on each static files.

For such publishing, is it better to use static files or to render the views each time its called? For any possible options, what ressources can I read that could help me with this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django can handle the caching of views and templates for you. There doesn't seem to be a very good reason to render static files for this.

You can use a custom view to check if the models are publicly available:

```
def view_public_object(request, object_id):
    object = get_object_or_404(Object, id=object_id)
    if object.is_published():
        return render_to_response('template.html', {'object': object})
    return Http404
```

If you're listing out all the objects that can be accessed, you can update the manager of the object to list only publicly available instances with this queryset:

```
Object.objects.filter(is_published=True)
```

Comment: You can also save the `is_published()` check by using a model manager to pre-filter `is_published=True` and using `get_object_or_404(Object.published, id=object_id)`

Comment: ok I think you are right, caching is probably the best avenue. I still wonder how to generate a unique address for per-views cache.

Comment: just use the id of the owner and the object_id put together or use a unique slug or hash of some of the fields of the object.

Comment: ok, so if I follow good, I dont need caching neither. Just a function like this one, a UrlConf that handle unique url and a is_published BooleanField in the app model.

Comment: I have an error 'Http404' has no attribute 'get' with `if object.is_published:` and have an error 'bool' object is not callable with `if object.is_published():`